# How to store images in db_files in attachment_fu plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, attachment-fu

In my rails application I have used attachment_fu plugin for image upload.

I am new on rails, I want to store file in attachment_fu db_files table.

How to store images in db_files and which path i want to specify to display images?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately attachment_fu does not support the same attachment "interface" for `:storage => :db_file` as it does for `:storage => :file_system`, but there's a plugin that fills the void here :

https://github.com/kares/attachment_fx

> Extends the file interface for the
>   :db_file backend (@see attachment_fu
>   :storage option). The database backend
>   interface mimics the :file_system
>   storage, the db data is on-demand
>   downloaded into the public directory
>   (the target path prefix is
>   customizable with the :path_prefix
>   option).

You basically use the `:file_system` methods like You're used to with the `:db_file` backend e.g. `photo.public_filename(:small)`. As a bonus You can enjoy some useful helpers from the owning model :

```
user.has_photo?
user.photo_path(:small)
user.photo_full_path
```